# Connecting to mysql from a remote PC gives error 10060

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mysql

First off, I am no programmer. I am a med student with decent computer knowledge; I've done this at least one time before in my home network.

Now, I am doing some research at my hospital, and for my database I want to use MySQL, running on a local network computer that can be connected to from laptops wirelessly.

So I download the MySQL installer, run it, and I connect via localhost perfectly well with the root account and the accounts I set up. I do bind-address to change its IP address to the computer's IP on the network, and I can connect again with root and with my accounts perfectly well on the machine the same server is on, using xx.xx.xx.xx + port to connect, with root and all other users.

However, using workbench on a laptop connected to the local network, I cannot connect with any user, it always gives error 10060.

- Firewall is off
- All AV software is off
- Accounts are set up correctly to allow connection from any host
- Client PC can ping server PC
- `netstat -anob` shows mysqld.exe listening on the port I need it to be listening to

The network here does block connections, but the port I'm using is open due to the fact it is used for another server type application that has very little to no traffic, so I just grabbed the opened ports for that application as they showed up in netstat and configured the server to use one of those ports.

How can i make sure the server PC is open at those ports?

The client I'm trying to connect with is either the MySQL workbench or heidisql. Neither can connect, however I have successfully used heidi before to connect to a database I have in DB4free.net. I cannot use that at the hospital, because the network shuts off the default port for MySQL which is what db4free.net uses.

Any ideas why I can't connect to that PC?

Even with the server ports open, is there a way to block the kind of connection heidisql or workbench use to connect to the MySQL server?

As an alternative, I also have a subdomain with database available in Hostinger, they do not allow remote connections however at the free tier. I've read using myqylog you can connect via HTTP tunneling to your hosted server if they only allow connections via localhost, but I would need a good amount of documentation to try that.

As a last resort, I can use MS SQL Express 2016 and make my own front end app via Visual Studio, but that would take a lot of time I don't really have.

Comment: Are you sure that the opened ports in the network aren't redirecting you to another server?

Comment: how can i check that? I jsut noticed on netstat that the local address is x.x.x.x:port im using, but external address is 0.0.0.0... that means it should take connections from everywhere, right?